ReplayFileName CAPL
I want to use the function ReplayFileName to load a blf source file via CAPL into my Replay Block. But my actual program isn't working properly.
includes
{
  
}

variables
{
  char replayName[32] = "Replay_Block_Test_case";
  char ReplayFileName[32] = "MEB_vel_MAX.blf";

}

on start
{
  replayStop(replayName);
  
}

on sysvar button::button
{
  if(@button::button == 1)
  {
    SetReplayFilename(replayName, ReplayFileName, "blf");
   
   replayStart(replayName);
   
  }
}


The name of my logfile is MEB_vel_MAX. Functions "replayStart" and "replayStop" work correctly, but the SetReplayFilename does not. How can I call my document so the function load it into the Replay Block? The variable "button" is linked to a button on my panel.
Thank you.

Please elaborate on "does not work"?
